# Why does the Ackermann function take so long in this Mouse interpreter written in C?

Tags: c, math, optimization, interpreter

I wrote the following [Mouse](http://mouse.davidgsimpson.com/) program to compute the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function):

```
~ Ackermann function in Mouse.
~ A(0,n) = n+1
~ A(m,0) = A(m-1,1)
~ A(m,n) = A(m-1,A(m,n-1))

1 a:  ~ set a to 1
7 b:  ~ set b to 2

#Y, a. b.;  ~ call ack like Y(a, b);

$Y 1% n: 2% m:               ~ ack
  m. 0 = k:                  ~ store whether m == 0 in k
  n. 0 = j:
  j. k. > [                    ~ if y>x (m==0)
    n.1+!                      ~ add 1 + print it
  | j. k. < [                  ~ else if x>y (n==0)
    #Y, m. 1-, 1;!             ~ call ack like Y(m-1, 1)
  | #Y, m. 1-, #Y, m.,n. 1-;;! ~ else, ack like Y(m-1, Y(m, n-1))
    ]
   ]
  ]
@ ~ end ack
$ ~ end prog
```

You can test it using [this](https://github.com/catb0t/newmouse/blob/master/mouse.c) interpreter written in C. Perhaps it's to do with mouse being stack-based, but this simple program doesn't finish for at least 15 minutes (I got impatient and it was hogging all my CPUs).

In Golang or Python, `Ackermann(1, 7)` or even `Ackermann(3, 10)` compute in a second or less.

Is there a fault in the compiler/interpreter (and what can I do to improve it?), or is my algorithm in Mouse terrible?

---

Note: [here](http://mouse.davidgsimpson.com/mouse2002/mouse_c.txt) is the original (well commented!!) version of the interpreter, which requires bugfixing before `gcc` agrees to compile it.

Comment: Does the interpreter translate to byte code, or is it a straight interpreter? Interpreters tend to be slow compared to compiled languages, and Ackerman's function is designed to be expensive. That combination is likely to be a perfect storm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about third-party code.

Comment: @Barmar it's a straight interpreter; it doesn't compile or assemble.

Comment: The interpreter immediately prints a (very long and cryptic) error message, apparently because of a stack overflow. Doesn't hog anything. I have no idea why anyone should spend any amount of time debugging this. Note that the first interpreter you link requires fixing a dozen or so broken format strings.

Comment: @n.m. It's not an error message; that's the program's output.

Comment: @n.m. make sure you used [this](https://github.com/catb0t/newmouse/blob/master/mouse.c) version of the interpreter which has an increased stack size

Comment: If normal program output comes from a function named `error`, that's one more reason to never look at this code again. Yes I have used this version and increased the stack size myself too. I want my 15 minutes back.

Answer (score 1):

On the question of why is it slower than Python or Go, that's probably because writing and developing high performance interpreters and compilers is very hard.  Python and Go have probably had way more work done on them.  Python, for example, did not always perform as well as it does now and is an important language that gets a lot of attention.

As with most things, it's horses for courses.  The choice of programming language is about what it's most suited to.  There are things which are tedious to do in e.g. C that are a snip in Python, but for high performance I'd generally go with C.